# OneDrive-API create folder if not exist

Tags: uwp, onedrive

I'm working on a Windows 10 UWP App, that makes use of the `OneDrive API` in c#.

I'm trying to get the `Id` of a specific sub folder or create it, if it does not exist. So far it looks something like this:

```cs
public async Task<string> getOldFolder<IDBEntry>(IDBEntry objectType)
{
try
{
    // authenticate
    if (!this.oneDriveClient.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        await this.oneDriveClient.AuthenticateAsync();
    }

    var children = await oneDriveClient.Drive.Special.AppRoot.Children.Request().Select("name,id").GetAsync(); // get name and id only (dont need the rest)
    string retID = string.Empty;

    string ID = string.Empty;
    if (children != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in children)
        {
            var s = item.Name;
            if (s == objectType.GetType().Name) // class name, e.g. "classA"
            {
                ID = item.Id;
            }
        }
    }

    // cancel, if nothing found
    if (ID == string.Empty)
    {
        return null;
    }

    children = await oneDriveClient.Drive.Items[ID].Children.Request().GetAsync();
    if (children != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in children)
        {
            if (item.Name == "old")
            {
                retID = item.Id;
            }
        }
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(retID))
    {
        // create folder "old"
        // this is the part I'm stuck with
        string itemPath = objectType.GetType().Name + "/" + "old";
        Item item = await oneDriveClient.Drive.Special.AppRoot.ItemWithPath(itemPath).Content.Request().PutAsync
        if (item != null && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Id)))
        {
            retID = item.Id;
        }
    }

    return retID;
}
catch (Exception)
{
    return null;
}
}
```

What does the code do? I put in a Class, e.g. `ClassA`, then it looks in the `Special Folder`, where only my App has access for this `ClassA` and searches for a folder called `old`. If it exists, it's returns the `Id` of folder `old` or it creates folder `old` and then returns it `Id`.

As you can see, my approach is not very nice looking, but I do not know, how to do it better, nor make it run (creating the folder is the issue here). I could upload a null file and thereby creating the folder automatically and then remove it again, but I do not wish to do it that way.

How can I approach this better and more professionally? Tahnk you very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I put in a Class, e.g. ClassA, then it looks in the Special Folder, where only my App has access for this ClassA and searches for a folder called old. If it exists, it's returns the Id of folder old or it creates folder old and then returns it Id.

I can't understand your `ClassA` here, you mean you want to do this work in a `Class` of your app?

Any way, I wrote a sample here, which can get my app's folder in the `OneDrive`, and find if there is a sub folder named "old" inside, if yes, return the ID of this folder, if not, create one and return the ID of this new folder.

```cs
private string ID;

private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var appfolderitems = await GetAppRoot();
        Dictionary<string, string> itemList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (var item in appfolderitems)
        {
            var id = item.Id;
            var name = item.Name;
            itemList.Add(id, name);
        }
        if (itemList.ContainsValue("old"))
        {
            foreach (var item in itemList)
            {
                if (item.Value == "old")
                    ID = item.Key;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ID = await CreateFolder();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}

private IOneDriveClient driveClient;

private async Task<IChildrenCollectionPage> GetAppRoot()
{
    driveClient =
        await OneDriveClientExtensions.GetAuthenticatedUniversalClient(
            new string[] { "onedrive.readwrite", "offline_access" }
            );

    if (!driveClient.IsAuthenticated) return null;

    var itemRequest = await driveClient.Drive.Special.AppRoot.Children.Request().GetAsync();
    return itemRequest;
}

private async Task<string> CreateFolder()
{
    if (!driveClient.IsAuthenticated) return null;
    var folderToCreate = new Item { Name = "old", Folder = new Folder() };
    var oldfolder = await driveClient.Drive.Special.AppRoot.Children.Request().AddAsync(folderToCreate);
    return oldfolder.Id;
}
```

As you can see here, I put the code for getting ID in a Button click event, if you want to access it in a Class, you may try to put this code in your class's constructor.

By the way, I didn't use Search and Filter Api here to find the folder, my purpose was to distinguish folder named "old" and files named "old", for example "old.txt", by default if you search for "old", the "old.txt" will also be added to the result. For now I didn't find a way to use `Q` filter to search for the specific type, you can have a try.

Comment: Hmmm I think the `ClassA` thing is more confusing in the question, than helping. Anyway, your answer is, what I hoped for. The thing with the class is, that I have an interface and multiple classes inherit this interface. The classes are entries of a Database and i want to put each entry of a class into a shared folder. The name of each entry determines, if the it is newer or the same while synching and I can go without the sync delta, which is still quite confusing for me.

Comment: @user3079834, sounds quite complicated to me, where is your Database? Is that not OK if you just upload your database file onto OneDrive? Any way, if you have any other problem, welcome to ask a new question here.

Comment: Feng: The Database is locally, but I want to sync to multiple devices and as the user will make changes to the database and or adding entries quite often, I found synching the db each time as too much in time and data usage, so I chose to rather sync each entry itself and when it's changed, I just have to download that specific entry. that's where the interface and the classes come in play: each entry has it's own unique ID and a datetime it was last updated. This combined makes the filename on OneDrive. As I mentioned in the post above, this is not professionally, but I think works